# use Axios, aynsc/await and typescript, I don't know this situation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I make a workflows list using axios response
but error occurs

```
Argument of type 'Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<WorkflowForReactFlowProps[] | null>'.
```

this Axios code

```
export const requestWorkflows = async () => {
  try {
    const response: AxiosResponse = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/workflows`);
    const workflows = formatWorkflows(response.data.workflows);
    return workflows;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

this state and useEffect code

```
const [workflows, setWorkflows] =
    useState<Array<WorkflowForReactFlowProps> | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => setWorkflows(requestWorkflows()), []);
```

why occurs this error?
and what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

An async function always returns a promise. You can see it from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#:%7E:text=Async%20functions%20always%20return%20a,implicitly%20wrapped%20in%20a%20promise.). To make your code work, you need to change these lines:

```
    const workflows: WorkflowForReactFlowProps[] | null = formatWorkflows(response.data.workflows);
```

---

```
useEffect(async () => setWorkflows((await requestWorkflows())), []);
```